# Retaining newlines and other content when reading in a screenplay in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I figure read.lines() or maybe the tm package will be the way to go for this, but I was wondering what recommendations folks have for reading a .txt screenplay. Demarcating parts of the screenplay will require case-sensitive and newline-sensitive regexes and such, so I need to preserve all those elements in the content that is read. Thoughts?

Comment: Ok it looks like read_file() in tidyverse is best for this.

Answer (score 0):

read_file() in the tidyverse package does a nice job of this.